# Can a using-declaration appear at block/function scope?

Tags: c++

My question is pretty much the title. 
Example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   using std::cout; //legal?
   { 
      using std::cin; //legal?
   }
}
```

Comment: No problem. Backticks don't work to format code over multiple lines. Multiline code blocks must be indented by 4 spaces.

Comment: s/iostrean/iostream Can't edit myself yet.

Comment: What's the reason for downvoting the question?

Comment: @Daniel. No, it's not. There are many things that would compile on my compiler (MSVC9.0) which are NOT legal. I don't know why I started doubting about this so I asked here.

Comment: So why don't try to use it. Add cin inside of scope where using cin, also add cin (without the std::) outside scope. Also can you give an "example" of illegal thing that compiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 7.3.3 The using declaration

> A using-declaration introduces a name into the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears.

And, since someone asked in a comment about `using namespace`:

- 7.3.4 Using directive

> A using-directive shall not appear in class scope, but may appear in namespace scope or in block scope.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's legal. In fact, it's preferred over doing it at file scope...

Comment: I am sorry but I haven't heard of such a thing as a file scope

Comment: Does the same apply to `using namespace`?

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you test it? It works alright.